# openweathermap api json volley response returning empty

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley, openweathermap

My API url works in a browser, but for some reason all fields for the json object are returning as null. I have added the necessary internet permissions in the manifest, and am not sure why my objects are all null at the end of my api request. Here is my code:

```
private lateinit var requestQueue : RequestQueue
private lateinit var weather : JSONArray
private lateinit var currentWeather : JSONObject
private var id = 0
private lateinit var mainWeather : String
private lateinit var description : String
private var singleDayUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid={apiKey}"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
    }

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val jsonObj : JsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            singleDayUrl, null,
            Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response -> weather = response.getJSONArray("weather")
                currentWeather = weather.getJSONObject(0)
                id = currentWeather.getInt("id")
                mainWeather = currentWeather.getString("main")
                description = currentWeather.getString("description")},
            Response.ErrorListener() { /**/ })
    requestQueue.add(jsonObj)
}
```

I am using the following imports:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.haacke.android_p3.ui.main.MainFragment
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.VolleyError
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
```

When I debug at the end of this function, all the variables (weather, currentWeather, etc...) are showing null. In fact, I think the entire response might be empty. My logcat shows nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I added a Log.i for the response message and alas, it shows nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason everything was showing null is that I was setting a breakpoint directly after the request function and not inside the listener itself. Therefore, the listener never heard the response yet when I arrived at my initial breakpoint. By setting my breakpoints inside the listener, a response had been heard, and the values were no longer empty.